# How to create a text field in Google Apps Script Templates?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is what I tried:

```
<label for"API Key">API Key</label>
<input type = "text"
             id = "myText"
             value = "text here" />
```

I don't have any custom variables passed from the code in so I don't believe I need any fancy template  like that. Right now I get;

```
Malformed HTML content:<label for"API Key">API Key</label> <input type = "text" id = "myText" value = "text here" /> </body> </html> .
```

Bonus points for someone who explains where they found this information! Ive been scouring documentation and stack overflow for a while now with no results. I want to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an equal sign missing, and the "for" attribute must match the "id" attribute setting

Should be:

```
<label for="myText">
```

[Link to Information](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp)

If you do not need server code to look up some information and inject it into the HTML, then you don't need to use a template.

Comment: Haha wow. Well I guess that is the answer. Too bad the question was just about a typo. thanks for the server code clarification